# Verifying html form using ajax synchronous request

Tags: html, ajax, firefox, synchronous

**TLDR**: Can the `onreadystatechange` event be emulated somehow else for synchronous requests without freezing the browser, as it does not get fired in Firefox?

~~~~~

I have created a web form that needs verification and to get some elements from the server before actually being submitted.

What I do now, is that `'onsubmit'` I fire an ajax request to my server, send the form details, parse them server side, and return a unique verification number and a md5 hash to the form.

The way it is meant to work is that the form should receive the reply and then proceed to submit the form. I must note that the actual form submission is a normal `POST` submission without ajax - the form is posted to a server outside my control.

I suppose I need to do a synchronous ajax request - not asynchronous as it is often used for. The point is that the form should never be submitted before getting the reply, simply because it will fail, as the reply contains important fields that the server on the other side will look for.

I tested Chrome and everything seems to work fine with synchronous requests. I do the request, and `onreadystatechange` I fire the handler to parse the reply.

But Firefox does not fire the `onreadystatechange` event in synchronous requests. This behavior is there from version 1.5 or something.

What most people do, as I've seen, is to run the handler anyway at some point - because the response is received and is in the DOM (responseText), just the `onreadystatechange` event doesnt get fired.

But this does not work for me: Depending on where on the code I run it, the response may not be available yet, so parsing it will fail.

I've tried two solutions, both of them bad:

- Use a synchronous request, and put the handler on a while loop, waiting for the reply.
- Use a asynchronous request, and have a while(myvariable); to wait until the reply gets there (myvariable is the reply I get from the server, after handling the responseText.

Both of these of course cause Firefox to freeze for quite some time, as Javascript waits in a `while` loop. In the end it works fine, if the anti-freeze protections of Firefox don't kick in and say that a script on this page is not responding.

What would you suggest? Can I do a while loop without freezing the browsers? Maybe a polling thingie that doesnt poll every millisecond as the while loop does, but every 1 second lets say, so the script doesn't freeze?

Comment: @Charlie - actually, that's four words.... ;)

Comment: @Spudley: The term [acronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym_and_initialism#Nomenclature)  is the name for a word created from the first letters of each word in a series of words, so i can count TLDR as one word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your request is synchronous, then once the send() call returns the reply is completely available.  That's the whole point of synchronous requests.  Why do you need to do any sort of looping at all in that case?

Comment: wow - If thats the case I fail hard (epicly?) at ajax - going to check!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to why you are using the split validation approach.  The typical case is usually more along the lines of:

1. Use some JavaScript code to catch really obvious errors (missing/empty fields, etc.).
2. If there are no obvious errors, submit the form.  If the server-side validation fails then the server sends the user back to the same form, with the errors marked/explained.

However, you don't need a synchronous AJAX request to get what you want.  All you need to do is cancel the `onsubmit` event while the AJAX validation is happening, and then manually submit the form once you get the response back from the server.  So you might set your form up like:

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="doAjaxValidation(); return false;">
    <!-- input fields, etc. -->
</form>
```

...and then your response handler might do something like:

```
//check the response to make sure everything was valid, add required data to the form, etc.

if (validationWasSuccessful) {
    //validation successful, submit the form
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

Note that you will most likely want to disable all the input fields in the form while the validation is being processed.  Otherwise if your server is having a slow day for whatever reason and validation takes 10 seconds then the user might change the data in the form while it is being validated, thus causing the subsequent form submission to fail.  And also note that even if you disable the form, that still won't stop a determined user from using something like Chrome's JavaScript console to edit field values during the validation phase.

Both of those issues go away if you can find some way to get rid of the split validation and submit approach.  And your workflow becomes more efficient, as well.  Round-trips to the server are expensive.

Comment: Thanks about this tip, I will look into it asap. As for the split validation, it's not actually that. Only once validation takes place: Through ajax, before submitting the form. If everything works ok, then the form is submitted to a different server, not in my control. I just need to validate the form before the actuall submit happens, thats the problem. And the kind of validation I am doing can only be done server-side (thus ajax) because I calculate a hash of the inputs (and a server nonce) and send it to the form, to be included in the POST for the other server.